# Javascript changing Attribute value from another HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, embed, frame

I have a little site, not yet online but that doesn't matter. Inside I have two frames:

```
<html>
<frameset border="transparent" cols="63%,37%">
<frame src="A.html" name="A" NORESIZE>
<frame src="B.html" name="B" NORESIZE>
</frameset>
</html>
```

In frame A there is a button.

```
<html>
<body>
<input onClick="#" type="button"/>
</body>
</html>
```

In frame B there is a youtube video:

```
<html>
<body>
<object id="obj" name="obj" width="100%" height="100%">
<param id="param" name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/url"/>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"/>
<embed id="embed" name="embed" src="http://www.youtube.com/url"" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%" height="100%" allowfullscreen="true"/>
</object>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I'm trying to let the embed's source and the parameter's (named movie) value change into another url.
 I've tried a lot of codes. The following Javascript codes, for example, won't work:

```
top.frames["B"].document.getElementById("movie").value = 'http://www.youtube.com/otherurl';
top.frames["B"].document.getElementById("embed").src = 'http://www.youtube.com/otherurl';
```

So if anyone know how to do these codes right or how to get the same result with other codes, I'd really appreciate it.
Anticipated thanks, VVW.

Comment: Frames?! That's so 90's! [Don't use frames!](http://www.html-faq.com/htmlframes/?framesareevil)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to anyone who answered. I experimented a bit with all of the codes and my result is actually very simple.

```
top.frames["divtest"].document.getElementById("embed").setAttribute('src','http://www.youtube.com/v/lPMx86wXaKY?version=3&amp;hl=nl_NL');
top.frames["divtest"].document.getElementById("param").setAttribute('value','http://www.youtube.com/v/lPMx86wXaKY?version=3&amp;hl=nl_NL');
```

I wonder why I didn't come up with that earlier so I appologise to everyone and thank you all for all the help.
VVW

Answer (score 1):

Your DOM is broketh:

Change `<param id="param" name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/url"`

to .. `<param id="param" name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/url" />`

Comment: @ AlienWebGuy:<br>Sorry, isn't the problem, type fault. Thanks for trying, the fault will be edited.

Answer (score 0):

From the parent you can't access nor manipulate elements in the child frame, it's a security measure, otherwise it would be easy to come out with malicious sites that wrap banking sites in iframes and the parent would read the password that you enter into it.

Don't do frames.

Comment: @ Carlos:<br>Interesting theorie but I've seen a tutorial example where a guy changed a textbox value in on frame using the other. The example really worked but when I insterted it into my codes with the youtube urls it did'nt work anymore. So it's a fact: it's possible.<br>
<a href="http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jframe1.htm">source</a><br><br>VVW

Comment: @Carlos - Not so.  This is only the case if the frames' contents come from different domains.  As long as each frame contains content from the same domain, access is unrestricted.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [YouTube JavaScript Player API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html).  Call [`player.loadVideoById()`](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#loadVideoById).  Make sure your original src URL contains `&enablejsapi=1`:

```
top.frames["B"].document.getElementById("embed").loadVideoById(id);
```

Comment: So I have to add &enablejsapi=1 to the original url,